# Editing items from a list within one form - MVVM approach

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

EDIT2:
I'm working on some project, where my ComboBox contains a list of editable elements. These elements are editable after one of them is selected. What I want is that the selected element's edited properties get remembered when I deselect it, and the ComboBox dropdown list gets updated with the new elements' descriptions. Here's how this example looks like:

[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr4S5.jpg)

Right now the change is remembered after the switch, but the dropdown list still contains the old names, and doesn't get auto updated:

[Dropdown List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SKuU.jpg)

Here's the code.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MVVM ComboBox edit sample" Height="372.52" Width="415.214">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="81*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="44*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Things}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedThing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}">Add Item</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloneCommand}">Clone Item</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}">Delete Item</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Margin="0"  >Name</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Margin="0"  >Price</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample.MockModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample
{
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Thing> things;
        private Thing selectedThing;

        private ICommand addCommand;
        private ICommand cloneCommand;
        private ICommand deleteCommand;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>(ThingDataManager.Instance.GetThings());
            SelectedThing = Things.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things
        {
            get
            {
                return things;
            }

            set
            {
                things = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Things));
            }
        }

        public Thing SelectedThing
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedThing;
            }

            set
            {
                selectedThing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedThing));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
                //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Things));
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedThing != null)
                {
                    return SelectedThing.Name;
                }
                return null;
            }

            set
            {
                SelectedThing.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        public string Price
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedThing != null)
                {
                    return SelectedThing.Price;
                }
                return null;
            }

            set
            {
                SelectedThing.Price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if(addCommand==null)
                {
                    addCommand = new CommandBase(i => AddItem(), null);
                }
                return addCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand CloneCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if(cloneCommand==null)
                {
                    cloneCommand = new CommandBase(i => CloneItem(), null);
                }
                return cloneCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand DeleteCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if(deleteCommand==null)
                {
                    deleteCommand = new CommandBase(i => DeleteItem(), null);
                }
                return deleteCommand;
            }
        }

        public void AddItem()
        {
            Thing newThing = new Thing();
            Things.Add(newThing);
            SelectedThing = newThing;
        }

        public void CloneItem()
        {
            Thing clonedThing = new Thing();
            clonedThing.Name = SelectedThing.Name;
            clonedThing.Price = SelectedThing.Price;
            Things.Add(clonedThing);
            SelectedThing = clonedThing;
        }

        public void DeleteItem()
        {
            Thing tempThing = new Thing();
            tempThing = SelectedThing;
            if (Things.IndexOf(SelectedThing) != 0)
            {
                SelectedThing = Things.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else if (Things.Count==1)
            {
                SelectedThing = null;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedThing = Things[1];
            }

            Things.Remove(tempThing);
        }
    }
}
```

**Thing.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample.MockModel
{
    class Thing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**ThingDataManager**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample.MockModel
{
    class ThingDataManager
    {
        private static ThingDataManager _instance;

        public static ThingDataManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance==null)
                {
                    _instance = new ThingDataManager();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private ThingDataManager()
        {
        }

        public List<Thing> GetThings()
        {
            List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
            things.Add(new Thing { Name = "Book", Price = "12$" });
            things.Add(new Thing { Name = "Hammer", Price = "2$" });
            things.Add(new Thing { Name = "Fridge", Price = "1200$" });

            return things;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that the rest like ViewModelBase and CommandBase are self-descriptive enough :).

Any ideas why my dropdown list doesn't get updated with the current names of things?

EDIT:
OK, I uploaded the simplified version on github:

github.com/piotr-napadlek/MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample

What is still not working is that the items of ComboBox dropdown don't change when changing the values of the Name textbox. Also, please let me know if general approach in this example is correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems I've complicated it too much. Mapping Thing class' properties to another properties inside my ViewModel was redundant. Actually mapping TextBoxes on WPF window directly to SelectedThing.Name and SelectedThing.Price and calling OnPropertyChanged only on SelectedThing was enough to solve my issue. Here's the working version:

ViewModel:

```
using MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample.MockModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample
{
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Thing> things;
        private Thing selectedThing;

    private ICommand addCommand;
    private ICommand cloneCommand;
    private ICommand deleteCommand;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>(ThingDataManager.Instance.GetThings());
        SelectedThing = Things.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things
    {
        get
        {
            return things;
        }

        set
        {
            things = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Things));
        }
    }

    public Thing SelectedThing
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedThing;
        }

        set
        {
            selectedThing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedThing));
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(addCommand==null)
            {
                addCommand = new CommandBase(i => AddItem(), null);
            }
            return addCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand CloneCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(cloneCommand==null)
            {
                cloneCommand = new CommandBase(i => CloneItem(), i => SelectedThing!=null);
            }
            return cloneCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(deleteCommand==null)
            {
                deleteCommand = new CommandBase(i => DeleteItem(), i => SelectedThing!=null);
            }
            return deleteCommand;
        }
    }

    public void AddItem()
    {
        Thing newThing = new Thing();
        Things.Add(newThing);
        SelectedThing = newThing;
    }

    public void CloneItem()
    {
        Thing clonedThing = new Thing();
        clonedThing.Name = SelectedThing.Name + " - copy";
        clonedThing.Price = SelectedThing.Price;
        Things.Add(clonedThing);
        SelectedThing = clonedThing;
    }

    public void DeleteItem()
    {
        Thing tempThing = new Thing();
        tempThing = SelectedThing;
        if (Things.IndexOf(SelectedThing) != 0)
        {
            SelectedThing = Things.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else if (Things.Count==1)
        {
            SelectedThing = null;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedThing = Things[1];
        }

        Things.Remove(tempThing);
    }
}
```

}

MainView:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMEditComboBoxItemsSample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MVVM ComboBox edit sample" Height="372.52" Width="415.214">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="81*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="44*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Things}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedThing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}">Add Item</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloneCommand}">Clone Item</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}">Delete Item</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Margin="0"  >Name</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedThing.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="4" Margin="0"  >Price</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedThing.Price}"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sample project in this article, it will give you and idea for a good architecture for MVVM application.  It is using Silverlight, which is simply a stripped down version of WPF:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/854816/MVVM-Silverlight-Application-with-Entity-Framework